# Failed to download repository information. Check your internet connection.

Tags: software-updater

I changed software & update settings which may be the problem, what does the default for this look like?

I tried `sudo apt-get clean`,`sudo apt-get update`,`sudo apt-get upgrade`.
I also tried `software-properties-gtk` in terminal and it gave me:
`gpg: /tmp/tmp<somerandom>/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created.`

Comment: I updated the software about 2-3 hours ago and it worked fine but now I get the same problem has you. I haven't changed any settings so probaly is an ubuntu server problem, my server is Spain.

Comment: What exactly is the output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem. My server was Australia - I changed it to the main server in Software Manager and it was fixed.